# Table where columns have different numbers of rows

Tags: tables, multirow

I'm trying to make a multi column table, where the first column has n-1 rows as the rest of the columns. A visual sketch of what I'm looking for is:

```
     Date      | Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3
               |    X    |     X   |    X  
  DD/MM/YYYY   -----------------------------
               |    X    |     X   |    X  
  DD/MM/YYYY   -----------------------------
               |    X    |     X   |    X  
  DD/MM/YYYY   -----------------------------
               |    X    |     X   |    X
```

Using the `multicolumn` package, I've come somewhat close

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cccc}
        \hline
        Date      & Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 \\
        \multirow{2}{*}{DD/MM/YYYY}
        &X&X&X\\
        \cline{2-4} 
        &Y&Y&Y\\
        \multirow{2}{*}{DD/MM/YYYY}
        &Y&Y&Y\\
        \cline{2-4} 
        &Y&Y&Y\\
        \multirow{2}{*}{DD/MM/YYYY}
        &Y&Y&Y\\
        \cline{2-4} 
        &X&X&X\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Unsuccessful latex code output]

This is the closest I've been a able to come, but this approach produce an extra row for every use of the `\multirow`.  In effect all the values denoted as Y's in the latex example are redundant an only need to appear once.

I hope this is clear. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cccc}
        \hline
        Date      & Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 \\[4pt]
        \multirow{3}{*}{DD/MM/YYYY}    &X&X&X\\ [4pt]      \cline{2-4} 
        &&&\\
        \multirow{3}{*}{DD/MM/YYYY}   &Y&Y&Y\\  [4pt]      \cline{2-4} 
        &&&\\
        \multirow{3}{*}{DD/MM/YYYY}   &Y&Y&Y\\  [4pt]      \cline{2-4} &&&\\
        &X&X&X\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

By forcing to vertical overlap `\multirow` cells as you do in your question. So you may only add some vertical space in cells:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow} % <---

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\setcellgapes{5pt} % <---
\makegapedcells    % <---
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cccc}
        \hline
        Date      & Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 \\[4pt]
        \multirow{2}{*}[-2pt]{DD/MM/YYYY}   & X & X & X \\  \cline{2-4}
        \multirow{2}{*}[-2pt]{DD/MM/YYYY}   & Y & Y & Y \\  \cline{2-4}
        \multirow{2}{*}[-2pt]{DD/MM/YYYY}   & Z & Z & Z \\  \cline{2-4} 
                                            & X & X & X \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{cccc}
\toprule
Date & Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 \\[1mm]
     & X       & X       & X \\
DD/MM/YYYY & \Cdots[line-style=solid] \\
     & Y       & Y       & Y \\
DD/MM/YYYY & \Cdots[line-style=solid] \\
     & Z       & Z       & Z \\
DD/MM/YYYY & \Cdots[line-style=solid] \\
     & X       & X       & X \\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]